# Create new Complex XML file for each row of excel data.. As shown below

Tags: javascript, java, excel, xml, vba

I have some 5K records of Excel data which needs to be converted into 5K XML files. For each row of excel there should be an XML file created. I tried using VBA but as the number of lines are more it's not working as expected. Could you please help me here please.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<comtec version="2010">
    <transport_order>
        <id>1234</id>
        <order_number>1234</order_number>
        <priority>0</priority>
        <order_date>2022-06-25T00:00:00.000Z</order_date>
        <order_status>
            <code>Placed</code>
        </order_status>
        <contact>
            <id>xyz</id>
            <code>xyz</code>
            <name>xyz</name>
        </contact>
        <contactId>xyz</contactId>
        <productId>abc</productId>
        <amounts>
            <amount>
                <unit_code>xy</unit_code>
                <value>1.0</value>
            </amount>
            <amount>
                <unit_code>yz</unit_code>
                <value>2.0</value>
            </amount>
            <amount>
                <unit_code>Total</unit_code>
                <value>1.0</value>
            </amount>
            <amount>
                <unit_code>Kg</unit_code>
                <value>17.24</value>
            </amount>
            <amount>
                <unit_code>zx</unit_code>
                <value>1.0</value>
            </amount>
        </amounts>
        <department>
            <code>2345</code>
            <name>2345</name>
        </department>
        <department_code>2345</department_code>
        <pickup_task>
            <address>
                <id>2345</id>
            </address>
        </pickup_task>
        <delivery_task>
            <address>
                <id>1234</id>
                <code>1234</code>
                <address_kind_code>Xyz</address_kind_code>
                <street_name>woifewnncs</street_name>
                <zipcode>Xyz</zipcode>
                <city>Xyz</city>
                <state_name/>
                <country_code>Xy</country_code>
                <givenX></givenX>
                <givenY></givenY>
                <temporary>true</temporary>
                <plan_region_code>default</plan_region_code>
            </address>
            <task_window>
                <from_instant>2022-06-21T11:00:00.000Z</from_instant>
                <till_instant>2022-06-21T12:00:00.000Z</till_instant>
            </task_window>
            <duration>123</duration>
        </delivery_task>
    </transport_order>
</comtec>
```

Comment: Please explain whats not working as this is rather to broad.

Comment: If you already tried VBA then maybe a good idea to post that.  Otherwise there's nothing for us to review.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can create such nested XML in VBA from scratch

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const FORMAT_DATETIME As String = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:nn:ss\.\0\0\0\Z"
    Dim oDoc            As Object
    Dim sXml            As String
    
    Set oDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With oDoc
        With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("comtec"))
            .setAttribute "version", 2010
            With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("transport_order"))
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("id")).Text = 1234
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("order_number")).Text = 1234
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("priority")).Text = 1234
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("order_date")).Text = Format$(Now, FORMAT_DATETIME)
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("order_status"))
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("code")).Text = "Placed"
                End With
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("contact"))
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("id")).Text = "xyz"
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("code")).Text = "xyz"
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("name")).Text = "xyz"
                End With
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("contactId")).Text = "xyz"
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("productId")).Text = "abc"
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amounts"))
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amount"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("unit_code")).Text = "xy"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("value")).Text = "1.0"
                    End With
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amount"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("unit_code")).Text = "yz"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("value")).Text = "2.0"
                    End With
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amount"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("unit_code")).Text = "Total"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("value")).Text = "1.0"
                    End With
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amount"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("unit_code")).Text = "Kg"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("value")).Text = "17.24"
                    End With
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("amount"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("unit_code")).Text = "zx"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("value")).Text = "1.0"
                    End With
                End With
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("department"))
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("code")).Text = "2345"
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("name")).Text = "2345"
                End With
                .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("department_code")).Text = "2345"
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("pickup_task"))
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("address"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("id")).Text = "2345"
                    End With
                End With
                With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("delivery_task"))
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("address"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("id")).Text = "2345"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("code")).Text = "2345"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("address_kind_code")).Text = "Xyz"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("street_name")).Text = "woifewnncs"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("zipcode")).Text = "Xyz"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("city")).Text = "Xyz"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("state_name")).Text = ""
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("country_code")).Text = "Xy"
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("givenX")).Text = ""
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("givenY")).Text = ""
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("temporary")).Text = True
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("plan_region_code")).Text = "default"
                    End With
                    With .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("task_window"))
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("from_instant")).Text = Format$(Now, FORMAT_DATETIME)
                        .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("till_instant")).Text = Format$(Now, FORMAT_DATETIME)
                    End With
                    .appendChild(oDoc.createElement("duration")).Text = "123"
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
    If FormatXmlIndent(oDoc, sXml) Then
        Debug.Print "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf & sXml
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FormatXmlIndent(vDomOrString As Variant, sResult As String) As Boolean
    Dim oWriter         As Object

    On Error GoTo QH
    Set oWriter = CreateObject("MSXML2.MXXMLWriter")
    oWriter.omitXMLDeclaration = True
    oWriter.Indent = True
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.SAXXMLReader")
        Set .contentHandler = oWriter
        '--- keep CDATA elements
        .putProperty "http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", oWriter
        .parse vDomOrString
    End With
    sResult = oWriter.Output
    '--- success
    FormatXmlIndent = True
    Exit Function
QH:
End Function
```

Another option is to use `LoadXml` with a template XML and modify (empty) values from data in current row.